# Python sqlalchemy calling stored procedure

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to call a `stored procedure` from `python` using `sqlalchemy`. The code I have is as follows:

```
@database_connection_wrapper
def get_adv(connection):
    ''' get the adv using a stored proc from the database '''

    connection.callproc("GetAdvMedianTrailing30Days")
    results = list(connection.fetchall())
    print(results)
```

I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Connection' object has no attribute 'callproc'`

I followed the instructions on the official documentation but that did not make a difference.

I am on `python 3.5`

Is there a different way to call `stored procedures`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures, `pyodbc` does not implement `.callproc()` method on the connection object. You must execute the sp using a SQL call (`.execute("{CALL GetAdvMedianTrailing30Days}")`).

(This isn't really a SQLAlchemy question since you are leaking the abstraction down to make a DB-API call using `pyodbc`)

Comment: Thanks! I get an error that `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'GetAdvMedianTrailing30Days', database 'XXX', schema 'dbo'. (229) (SQLExecDirectW)")`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does the user you are using sqlalchemy to log into the server with have the necessary permissions to execute `GetAdvMedianTrailing30Days` in that database?

Comment: Will have to ask my team :P . The github link you posted is really helpful, since my stored proc returns values I will have to convert it into a `SQL` statement I think. Thanks again!

Comment: The error you are getting implies the problem is permissions on the db server, not related to python.

Comment: yeah, i thought so too. I will have to look into `SQL` permissions for the user I am using.

Comment: Does seem a shame that you have to use cursors/recordsets in Python when interacting with MS SQL Server.  I am not an expert but it seems much more elegant in C# with Command Objects.